# How not to receive a char which is not a number in scanf for double values.

Tags: c, char, double, scanf

I want in this little piece of code to insert double values and get the returned values as written, but in case I enter another character, besides numbers, I want the returned value to be 0.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int LegalInputChecker(double Move);

int main()
{
    double Move;
    int res;
    scanf("%lf", &Move);

   res = LegalInputChecker(Move);

   return res;

}

int LegalInputChecker(double Move)
{

    if(Move-(int)Move == 0 && (Move>0 && Move<=7))
    return 1; 

    else if((Move<0 || Move>7) && (Move-(int)Move == 0))
    return 2; 

    else if(Move==0)
    return 3;  

    else
    return 0;

}
```

for some reason, when I enter a letter for example, I keep getting the returned value "3", whats the reason?

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of items successfully matched. `if (!scanf(...) Move  = 0;`

Comment: @EOF , I think the OP wants `res=0` in case of invalid input, not `Move=0`

Comment: @CoolGuy: I'm sure he'll figure out how to modify my pseudocode appropriately...

Answer (score 3):

When you enter invalid data such as a character for

```
scanf("%lf", &Move);
```

`scanf` will fail and will return 0. So, just check the return value of `scanf`:

```
if(scanf("%lf", &Move) != 1) //If scanf failed due to invalid input or EOF
    res = 0;
else
    res = LegalInputChecker(Move);
```

> for some reason, when I enter a letter for example, I keep getting the returned value "3", whats the reason?

When you enter a character, `Move` will be untouched and is left uninitialized(Since you did not initialize it in the first place). Doing operations on this value results in Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you tell `scanf` already to read a `double` (longfloat). If you enter any illegal character, `scanf` wont store anything in your variable `Move` (which is uninitialized and may contain random data, in your case its content is `0`). If you want to make an own checker, you have to read char by char from input, check its value and the parse then whole input, if correct (there are functions for this, e.g. `atoll`) or output that user input has illegal characters.

Of course you could also check the return value of `scanf`, which will return `0` on fail.

Have a look here at [`man scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces undefined behavior.  The program returning the value `3` is one result in the boundless universe of outcomes permitted.

In particular, when this ...

```
scanf("%lf", &Move);
```

... is unable to scan even a single digit, the value of `Move` is not modified.  You have not initialized it or set its value any other way, though, so afterward accessing its value results in undefined behavior.  In this particular case, it appears that that is manifesting as if `Move` had been initialized to `0`, but you cannot rely on that or any other particular manifestation.

You can detect this condition via `scanf()`'s return value, which indicates the number of input items successfully matched and assigned.  You can get your desired result like this:

```
int main()
{
    double Move;

    if (scanf("%lf", &Move) == 1) {
        return LegalInputChecker(Move);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now a days the compilers are updated, my gcc compiler initializes the value to 0 automatically, this can also be the reason.

> But the correct answer and is given above and described perfectly by @*CoolGuy*.

Comment: "*if you insert a character as a input the scanf() assigns 0 to the value of Move.*" -- Wrong.

Comment: but I compiled it and tested it...@CoolGuy , I checked twice

Comment: It is Undefined Behavior. Any thing can happen. See my answer. `scanf` will not do anything to `Move` when it fails.

Comment: I saw your answer yesterday and totally support it, you are definitely, you are correct. But now I figure out why I am getting this, this is for the updated compiler, my gcc compiler automatically initializes to 0, sorry that is not the correct answer...@CoolGuy

Comment: Thanks for having the discussion with me...thanks for clearing my concept.@CoolGuy

Comment: Did you use a global variable `Move`? Or a `static Move`?

Comment: no local variable of main(), you also test it in ideone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77372/discussion-between-cool-guy-and-subinoy).